# How do I offset a point created at the midpoint of a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, expression, segment

I am trying to accomplish something similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93428/how-to-populate-fields-for-line-segment-with-value-from-polygon-to-left-and-righ), but in QGIS.

I am trying to create line segments from a polygon, while preserving on which side of the line, the polygon 'interior' is.

My idea is to create a point at the midpoint of each line segment, and then offset it onto each side of the line. I can then use a tool to check if the point is contained within the polygon, and mark each segment as "Interior_Left" and "Interior_Right"

Steps:

1. Polygon > line
2. Explode line to segments
3. Interpolate point at midpoint.  `$length/2`
4. **Where I need assistance** - Offset the point perpendicularly to both sides of the line, check if point is within polygon, and mark accordingly.

Now I am aware of GRASS plugin v.transform, but I don't know how I would offset it in relation to the azimuth of the line (perpendicular to the line segment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer starts with your step 3, thus you have exploded lines.

1. Use the following expression with Menu Processing / Tollbox /Geometry by Expression to create two points to the left and right of the midpoint (centroid) of each segment. I chose a value of 1 for the distance of the points from the line: change this values for your needs:

```
union (
    project (
        centroid ($geometry), 
        1, 
        radians (90) + azimuth (
            start_point ($geometry), 
            end_point($geometry)
        )
    ),
    project (
        centroid ($geometry), 
        -1, 
        radians (90) + azimuth (
            start_point ($geometry), 
            end_point($geometry)
        )
    )
)
```

2. As the resulting points are multipoints, use `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts`
3. Use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Intersection` and set the point layer resulting from step 2 as first input layer and the original polygons as second input layer. You now get all points that are inside a polygon.

*Screenshot, showing the results for 4 polygons: two were drawn clockwise, the other two countr clockwise so that "inside" and "outside" of the polygon is sometimes on the right and sometimes on the left. The red lines are for visualization purpose only:*

[image]